# Bibliography in LyX 2.0.0

Tags: bibtex, lyx

I am trying to insert bibliography in LyX 2.0.0 in the following steps.

1. First i select Bibliography from drop down menu.
2. Next i click on insert --> list/TOC  ---> Bibtex Bibliography ---> Add
3. And then i add Jabref Bib file.

But when I click on the button to make pdf file, I receive following error.

> Package natbib error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year
>   citations.

Hope that someone will help me.

Comment: You don't have to do the first step when using BibTeX. What does your .bib-file look like?